# ASP.NET Web API Serialize only public members or properties (ignore fields)

Tags: c#, json, wcf, asp.net-web-api, serialization

Is there a possibility in the ASP.NET Web API to define that only public members should be serialized or that only properties should be serialized?

The background is: We are storing the initial values for each property in a own private field (see example below). The problem now is that these fields are also serialized in our Rest Application, but that is not really useful, because this API is mainly used by external customers. It also not an option to remove the DataMember attributes, because we have also WCF services where this fields need to be serialized and transfered.

```
    [DataMember]
    private bool seasonNameIsInitialized;
    [DataMember]
    private string seasonName;
    [DataMember]
    private string seasonNameInitial;

    /// <summary>
    /// Season Name
    /// </summary>
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(100)]
    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(ResourcesModel), Name = nameof(ResourcesModel.SeasonName))]
    [DatabaseColumn(Name = "BEZ")]
    [DataMember]
    public string SeasonName
    {
        get
        {
            return seasonName;
        }
        set
        {
            string oldSeasonName = seasonName;
            seasonName = value;

            if (seasonNameIsInitialized)
            {
                OnPropertyChanged(oldSeasonName, seasonName);
            }
            else
            { 
                seasonNameInitial = value;
                seasonNameIsInitialized = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Different APIs, different DTOs. You can't create *one* DTO that handles self-contradicting requirements. Someone said *Your API model isn't your Resource model isn't your Domain model isn't your DTO Model isn't your Data model*

Comment: @jdwen what does an XML Serializer attribute have to do with Web API?

Comment: Using fields for serialization in SOAP isn't a good idea either. What does the *client* or *server* care about previous values or change notifications? This is just a DTO, not a domain entity. Are you trying to use the same class as a   domain entity and DTO for all APIs?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: But these two models would be completely the same with the exception of the DataMember attribut for some fields. As we have some hundred model classes it would need much work to do that. Which is not really an option for us. Is there no possibility to influence which members are serialized in the Web API?

Comment: So the two models aren't the same at all. And it sounds like you did try to use the same entity for both display, WCF and Web API. `OnPropertyChanged` has no meaning for a WCF DTO. Are you using the same class on the server and desktop perhaps?

Comment: They should not be the same. The WCF (SOAP) application is for internal use, so we need to know about all this information. The Rest-Application is for external customers, they do not need to get the additional fields.

Comment: so the APIs are *very* different. Different use cases, different models (RPC/Document  vs HTTP/Resources), different security requirements. Anyway, you can map between DTOs very easily with AutoMapper.

Comment: Yes of course, the API is very different. But the data is for 100 % the same, so I do not really see a use to create two nearly identical models just because of one attribute.

Comment: Wrong - four models. Database, WCF, REST, and display for at least one technology according to all those attributes. And you want both XML and REST serialization on the REST model, which means that you can't use any Xml-related attributed because it would affect the WCF endpoint as well. That's what the [One Thing To Rule Them All](http://deviq.com/one-thing-to-rule-them-all/) antipattern looks like. You can use `JsonIgnore` as a stop-gap measure, but this won't help with other problems

Comment: For example, public and internal APIs have *different* validation rules, which again are different from *database* validation rules. You won't accept a partially filled DTO from a *public* API, while an internal application is allowed to save intermediate versions of the same object. An internal application can just save an object. An external partner though, initiates a business transaction that needs logging, auditing

Comment: That is clear, but that is a totally different issue. The logging is not done by the models itself. Exception handling is not done by the model itself. The decision if an partially filled class is accepted is also done by other classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `JSon` serialization you  can use `NewtonSoft` by setting `[JsonIgnore]` attribute

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace JsonIgnore
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var obj = new myClass() { Age = 18, Name = "Max" };
            var selializedObj = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
            Console.WriteLine(selializedObj.ToString());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class myClass
    {
        [JsonIgnore]
        [DataMember]
        public int Age { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

with `[JsonIgnore]` attribute result is `{"Name" : "Max"}` ,
without `[JsonIgnore]` attribute result is `{"Name" : "Max", "Age" : 18}`

Comment: The OP added the `DataMember` attribute to explicitly demand serialization. I think JSON.Net understands both attributes. Would be fun to see how it behaves in this case. Is there a documented precedence or will the behaviour change from one release to the next

Comment: i have changed my answer and added small example

Comment: Is this *documented* or does it work simply because of the order the attributes are evaluated?

Comment: is there also a possibility to ignore xml? (Our Web API application supports both, json and xml)

Comment: if you ignore xml you will have problem with wcf

Comment: but you can create your separate view model for web api and everething will be ok

Comment: JsonIgnore is working perfectly. I think that will be my solution. Nobody uses our Rest API with XML, so it doesn't matter when we just remove the XmlFormatter

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - This is [documented behaviour](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationAttributes.htm)

Comment: @IvanR. This is still a stop-gap. The same class is used for as a database entity, display ViewModel, WCF document and REST DTO. Serialization problems are just the first crack in the foundations

Comment: yes, there should be separate viewmodel and he can work with 2 different objects separately using for example mapping for transfer values of objects

Comment: I agree with you but the question is about serialization, not about architecture issues.